# Passing Arrays.copyofrange into a method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, search

When given a array(in ascending order) or integers, I want to find the integer in the array in an efficient way. I check if the middle number of the array is equal to the number to check. If it is, great! If not, then I check if the number is greater than or less than the middle number. I cut the array in half and check again. However, I keep getting a value of zero.

```
public static int findNumber(int[] array, int number){
        int position = 0;
        int half = array.length/2;
        //System.out.println(array[half]);
        if (array[half]==number){
            position=array.length/2;
        }
        else if (array[half]<number){
            findNumber(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, half, array.length),number);
        }
        else if (array[half]>number){
            findNumber(Arrays.copyOfRange(array,0,array.length/2),number);
        }
        return position;
    }
```

The only exception to this is if the number checked is the exact middle number of the array. I think the error has to do with me not understanding how Arrays.copyOfRange(original, to: , from: ) works.

Comment: This approach is not correct and it will return a wrong result. How can you return the index in the actual array if you a changing it on every call ?  You should take a look at the binary search implementation, as it's what is used for

Comment: Per your description, you are trying to implement the binary search algorithm. Your approach to the problem is wrong. You must and don't need to change the original array in any way and certainly not copy its elements around. You only care about the middle element.

Comment: There is nothing efficient about using this method or any means where the **Arrays.copyOfRange()** method is used and recursively ripping through the supplied array (including the accepted answer, even if it worked). It's actually faster to simply iterate through the supplied array with a **for** loop and breaking out of it once the supplied number is found. Of course a means needs to be in place should the supplied number not exist in the array, for example: `return (i == array.length ? -1 : i);` where **i** is the iterator counter. **-1** would indicate **Not Found**. A lot less code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a value that keeps track of how many indexes are to the left of the range you pass back to the method on.

```
public static int findNumber(int[] array, int number){
     return(helper(array, number, 0);
}

public static int helper(int[] array, int number, int leftOf){
    int half = array.length/2;
    //System.out.println(array[half]);
    if (array[half]==number){
        return(half+leftOf);
    }
    else if (array[half]<number){
        return(
      helper(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, half, array.length),number,leftOf+half));
    }
    else if (array[half]>number){
        return(
      helper(Arrays.copyOfRange(array,0,array.length/2),number,leftOf));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a new error. When I try to test this in the main method, it gives me the error: Cant use non-static method in a static environment. How should I fix this?

Comment: I made the methods static in the answer. @DevilsHnd you need to make helper staic aswell

Comment: Oh...and can you please ensure that your answer at least compiles. It's missing some goodies. Thanks.

Comment: @DevilsHnd it compiles fine. However, I decided copying an Array is useless so I just scrapped it and redid the binary search

Answer (score 0):

According to java.util documentation Arrays.copyOfRange:

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array

In each recursion call you will get a new array in which the position of the searched item will be different from the original array.

Comment: For example, you can pass the entire array and two index: 'from' and 'to' which you can use to delimit where to find the number.